# How do I record my Output from a Python file?

Tags: python, logging

```
import random

# Random string of length 5
result_str = ''.join((random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()') for i in range(10)))
print(result_str)
```

This is my code and I am trying to generate random strings for my project and I want to record each and every single output from the file to notepad. Can anyone help me do so?

**It would be great if the process is automated as well.**

Example: I run the file and each output is recorded automatically on the file so I don't have to run the code again and again

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is, but you should write more concrete questions.

```
import random

with open("copy.txt", "w") as file:
    for i in range(10):
        file.write(random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

result_str = ''.join((random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()') for i in range(10)))
with open('file_output.txt','a') as out:
    out.write(f'{result_str}\n')
```